# jQuery calling focus() manually doesn't trigger the whole event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on or tab to a text input, this event gets triggered and works perfectly:

```
//highlight input contents and row/col when clicked
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    //highlight input contents
    $(this).select();

    //highlight new row/col
    $(this).parent().siblings().first().css({"color":"#f2f7fa"}); //row
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().children().eq(index).css({"color":"#f2f7fa"}); //col
});
```

However, when the focus() method is called manually...

```
//arrow keys move focus to adjacent cells
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left
        var $inputs = $('input[type=text]');
        $inputs.eq($inputs.index($('input[type=text]:focus')) - 1).focus();
    }
});
```

...the input contents are not highlighted, ie. select() doesn't work. But the text for the row/col is highlighted! So, only the second part of the function works! Why is that?

Comment: Calling `.focus()` won't trigger focus events. You can trigger the event manually with `.trigger('focus')` but it's usually better to call the function explicitly so that you don't end up in a recursive loop.

Comment: @mpen thank you, but if that's the case, how come the second part of the first function works when I call `.focus()` manually? That is, the part under `//highlight new row/col`?

Comment: Can't answer that. Maybe with a working example I could tell you what's going on.

Comment: @torjinx you need to prevent the default behaviour of the arrow key, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Apologies, my first answer was incorrect due to a misunderstanding of the question. Try this instead...

The problem is there is special behaviour tied to the arrow keys - I'm not sure specifically what is causing this, but preventing the default behaviour will fix it. (Third to last line below:)

```js
//highlight input contents and row/col when clicked
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    //highlight input contents
    $(this).select();

    //highlight new row/col
    $(this).parent().siblings().first().css({"color":"#f2f7fa"}); //row
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().children().eq(index).css({"color":"#f2f7fa"}); //col
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left
        var $inputs = $('input[type=text]');
        $inputs.eq($inputs.index($('input[type=text]:focus')) - 1).focus();
        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right
        var $inputs = $('input[type=text]');
        var nextIdx = $inputs.index($('input[type=text]:focus')) + 1;
        nextIdx = nextIdx >= $inputs.length ? 0 : nextIdx;
        $inputs.eq(nextIdx).focus();
        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
<input type="text" value="test">
<input type="text" value="test">
<input type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I think I understand - when the adjacent input was given focus, the default behavior of the arrow key then triggered which de-selected the text!

Comment: @torjinx yes I thought something along those lines might have been the cause, glad to hear it fixed it for you!